# pacemaker+corosync+DRBD 'unknown error' (1)

Tags: pacemaker, drbd

i have configured DRBD,corosync,pacemaker in mysystem..it works well when i have only one resource group. but i face the below problem when i added one more resource group.

crm_mon -f  // shows below error

Migration summary:
* Node cent64asf1:
* Node cent64asf2:
   r1_fs: migration-threshold=1000000 fail-count=1000000 last-failure='Sat Aug 23 18:00:45 2014'

Failed actions:
    r1_fs_start_0 on cent64asf2 'unknown error' (1): call=98, status=complete, last-rc-change='Sat Aug 23 18:00:45 2014', queued=107ms, exec=0ms